# DynamoDB Or condition with persistence model for .NET

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch data from dynamodb with OR condition but not able to get correct records.

I used below code

```
var conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
        conditions.Add(new ScanCondition("Status", ScanOperator.Equal, Status.VerficationPending));
        conditions.Add(new ScanCondition("Status", ScanOperator.Equal, Status.Verified));
        var config = new DynamoDBOperationConfig
        {
            ConditionalOperator = ConditionalOperatorValues.Or,
            QueryFilter = conditions
        };

        return await base.context.ScanAsync<Advertisement>(conditions, config).GetRemainingAsync();
```

With the above code, am getting records for Status Verified.

Comment: what are you trying to retrieve/achieve? its not very clear from your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to get all records where Status is Verified Or VerificationPending not other.